# Titanium android device http error

Tags: android, http, titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

i have a problem with titanium to comunicate with a my server in the network, 
the server's ip is 192.168.0.208 on the port 8000 (is a Node.js server).
If i call the server from the browser no problem but if i try to call the server from the application in Titanium i saw this error "The target server failed to respond" and in the server log no call is received

this is my network.js file in the application

```
    function HttpRequest(url, type, args, functionOnSuccss,functionOnError,timeout) {
    // args is json parameters  OPTIONAL
    Ti.API.log("[HTTP REQ] Call" + url);

    // ---#  ok string  ------
    var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
    xhr.open(type,url);
    xhr.cache = false;
    xhr.enableKeepAlive = false;
    xhr.timeout = timeout ? timeout : 500000;
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    //  xhr.setRequestHeader("Cookie", 'JSESSIONID=' + cookie + '');

    xhr.onload = function(e) {

            Ti.API.info("[HTTP] Response" + this.responseText);

            functionOnSuccss(this.responseText);

    };

    xhr.onerror = function(e) {
            Ti.API.info("ERROR " + e.error);
          //  alert("Connection Error");
            functionOnError(e.error);
    };
    if(args){
        xhr.send(args);
    }else{
    xhr.send();
    }
   };

   exports.request = HttpRequest;
```

and this is the coda that make the request

```
network = require('/library/network');
var sendCarrello = function() {
$.loader.visible = true;
$.carrelloCamminante.animate(a);
url = "192.168.0.208:8000/newMobileUser"; // or http://192.168.0.208:8000/newMobileUser it's the same
network.request(url, "get",undefined, function(resp) {
    alert(resp);
    $.loader.visible = false;
    }, function(err) {
        alert("error - "+""+err);
    });
 };
```

what could be the error?

Comment: try to set xhr.open(type,url); after  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

Comment: @AndreaGiglio no it's the same

Comment: Try to log whole request with headers made by browser / curl and Titanium client and compare it to see where is a difference. Recently I had problems with cookies saving in Titanium HTTPClient, it can also be wrong value in Content-Accept header.

Comment: i just try, but this is not the solution because the server accept all content-type request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use "GET" not "get" :

```
network.request(url, "GET",undefined, function(resp) { ....
```